# How to change the log4net rolling filenames to log_YYYMMDD_HHmmss.txt

Tags: log4net

I am maintaining some c# code and I want to log4net to store old log files as:

```
log_YYYMMDD_HHmmss.txt
```

eg:

```
log_20140617_193526.txt
```

I believe this is the relevant part of the config file, with my attempts at modifying it...

```
<appender name="HourlyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
        value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/Optex/RedwallServer/Log/log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.\tx\t" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="" />
    <param name="Footer" value="" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

It is producing a current log file of:

```
log.txt
```

And old log files are stored like:

```
log.txt20140617_193526.txt
```

Anyone any idea how I can change the prefix from "log.txt" to "log_"?

What I would really like is to figure this out myself, but I can't for the life of me find any decent documentation. I found this on rollingConfig but it is not what I'm after...
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have to change log.txt to log_:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
      value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/Optex/RedwallServer/Log/log_" />
```

Comment: Thanks, however the customer wants to keep the primary log file as log.txt